# 400 Error when posting to Google Vision API

Tags: google-cloud-vision

I had an application using the Google Vision API running fine for nearly a year. It wasn't running for a few months and when I ran it recently, it always returned 400 errors. I went to the account settings and noticed my key was gone. I entered a new one and updated my program. However, it still always gets a 400 error. It does so no matter what key I use (valid or not).

I looks like it isn't accepting the key.

Any idea what the issue might be?
Any way to test that a key is valid?

Comment: Do you have a code snippet? Have the exact error message?

Comment: Please share your code/tracebacks.